# What are the strategies for feature engineering in a hierarchical/relational structured data?

Tags: classification, regression, feature-engineering, hierarchical-data-format

I have a feature set with each feature having its own feature-set, and they are laid out in a SQL database with foreign key relationships. The target is defined on the top level feature-set and is a binary Win/Loss variable.

> Target;
>   feature -> sub-features->sub-features;
>   feature -> sub-features;

All the classification algorithms expect a flat feature file as an input. What are the methods for flattening out such a structured dataset, while preserving the cross feature dependence on the sub-feature set for other features?

How would you decide which sub-features to select? Currently I'm aggregating total Wins/Attempts and regressing (PCR) the individual sub features to see which ones have an influence over the final target, what would be a more generalized way of selecting these? And then combining these into a flattened feature?

I would also appreciate if someone can identify the correct machine learning jargon for this exercise.

Comment: The term you are looking for is [structured learning/prediction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_prediction).  Also look up "graph classification".

Comment: Hi Emre, while these links are relevant. I'm more curious about getting from a graph/ relational structure to a flat feature file, while preserving the sub feature correlations with other major features. I am trying to understand what feature engineering strategies are being applied to this end rather than directly applying machine learning algorithms to sub-features. While that would be theoretically desirable, I'm looking for a simpler yet explainable approach towards feature flattening.